# Using Merge into to update multiple rows in snowflake DB using python

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a snowflake table lets called it as (temp) with ID as my primary key which autoincrements with any new inserts in the table. I learned about merge into statement can be used to update multiple rows in the snowflake table.

I have a tkinter application, which retrieves the user input entered on the form using treeview method in python. I am looking how to update this table (temp) using the update statement for multiple rows for various columns? I am saving the user input variables using my internal function either in a list or a tuple that needs to be updated in the table temp. For example, if the user wants to change for all the five rows with ID IN (1,2,3,4,5) for the columns W1, W2, W3 how should I go about it?

In the snowflake documentation, I see it is using the target table and the source table.
Can this be possible? If so, how to go about it? If not, which alternate method I should follow? Thanks

```
################# Code template this is function, when user selects the update button on my tkinter app ############

Sql_Update= """ Update statement goes in here with parameters """

def Update_Fn():
 updates = self.records.selection()
 All_items = [self.records.item(i, 'values') for i in updates]
 #I get all the primary keys IDs that needs to be updated. 
 ID1 = All_items[0][0]
 ID2 = All_items[1][0]
 ID3 = All_items[2][0]
 ...............
 ## I get all the column entries that needs to be updated 
 var1 = W1.get()
 var2 = W2.get()
 var3 = W3.get() #etc.. Example for the first row entries 

 ctx = snowflake.connector.connect(
 user = ""
 password =""
 account = ""
 database = ""
) 
 cs = ctx.cursor()
 df = pd.read_sql(Sql_Update, ctx, params=param)
 ctx.commit()
 cs.close()
 ctx.close()


####### Trying to understand how to use the update for the multiple rows ########### 

merge into temp using "source table" ## I don't have a source table but values in a list or a tuple
on temp.ID = var.ID #value from one of the variable 
when matched then 
  update set temp.W1 = var2.W1
  temp.W2 = var3.W2.....;
```

| ID | Decision | W1 | W2 | W3 | Date | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | KLT Map | 5 | 0 | 2 | 11/30/2022 | python_beginner |
| 2 | PI Errors | 7 | 0 | 3 | 11/30/2022 | python_beginner |
| 3 | KI Logs | 8 | 8 | 3 | 11/30/2022 | python_beginner |
| 4 | Non_Issues | 9 | 8 | 4 | 11/30/2022 | python_beginner |
| 5 | Tickets | 87 | 5 | 1 | 11/30/2022 | python_beginner |

Answer (score 0):

Not a fancy solution but I am passing these updates statements as a list. Since I need only up to three update statements for this to work.

```
queries = [update1, update2, update3]
for i, q in enumerate(queries):
  df = pd.read_sql(q,con, param= params)
```